# Can saving context from multiple async calls completion handlers cause a core data race condition?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, race-condition

I am using NSURLSessionDataTask and in the completion handler I am saving the core data context. It is a single context setup.

When I fire 3 async tasks it is possible that they could return at the same time and try to save context at the same time, will this cause a race condition and if so how do I avoid that?

Comment: See: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html

Comment: That deals more with separating GUI from data processing, I am more interesting in keeping data processing from interfering with each other, for the instance of this question I am not worried of the user interface being blocked

Comment: No. That deals with using Core Data concurrently and gives you the tools you need to successfully use Core Data without running into race conditions and deadlocks. (When to create what kind of context, performing blocks (on contexts) aso.)

Comment: Plus: There is no reason to fire async tasks if you do not worry of the user main thread to be blocked.

Comment: There is no way to fire sync tasks using NSURLSession* I believe, implementation of op queues seems such overkill for such simple task